# Is there a way to set a context variable without calling assistant.message?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

Let me explain me better.

I'm developing a chatbot that may sell stuff, say... shirts, hoodies and so on, I have the information on a file within the server, we're using NodeJS for the backend.

I'm using the node-sdk from watson-developer-cloud
https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk

Now, imagine that I want to buy a shirt, so I send to the backend "I'd like to buy a shirt" and I call the assistant with the shirt entity, the chatbot detects the entity and sends the response back to me at the server, and I get the price from the file within the server, but now that I've already called the assistant.message to extract the entity I can't set the price as a context variable anymore.

What's the approach to do this kind of things?

Currently I have this working without saving the context variable. On a previous version I was saving the context with a fixed price, without extracting the entity, but I'd need to extract the entity AND LATER ON set the context.

Is there a way to set the context without calling assistant.message, or even better, get the entity without calling assistant.message? Works either way, or what approach should I be using?

I thought about calling assistant.message twice but I think that would be messy in the chatbot dialog flow, so I'd figure there's a better way to do it.

Comment: Add more details, it is not clear what is the programming issue. Have you seen this tutorial which shows a chatbot with backend database? https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/tutorials/slack-chatbot-database-watson.html

Comment: You should also look into what drives the the user interaction. https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/chatbot-best-practices

Comment: You should also look into the idea of calling a REST API from within Watson Assistant. You could call you server/db direct from within Assistant, and the response can be framed within a message response and set back to the user. This is becoming the default way to call external services from within Assistant.

Comment: It's not a programming issue itself rather a how-to question. I'll give it a read in a few hours.

Comment: timd you mean like using the 'actions' like in this repo? https://github.com/IBM/watson-assistant-app-connect/blob/master/server.js I can give it a shot, but I think theybuse 2 assistant.messagenin this approach, but maybebit's the way to go. I'll read data_henrik's link when I get off work later today.